# Are the higher level libraries unnecessary for STM32F042?

Tags: embedded, usb, stm32

I have been working with the STM32F30x series for a while and am used to the file system looking something like this:

```
inc/
---*.h
lib/
---CMSIS/
---STM32F30x_StdPeriph_Driver/
------inc/
------scr/
---STM32_USB-FS-Device-Driver/
------inc/
------scr/
src/
---*.c
usb/
---inc/
------ hw_config.h
------ *.h
---scr/
------ hw_config.c
------ *.c
```

Now I'm switching to work with a STM32F042 and I'm utterly unable to find the usb library with the hw_config and usb files so my setup is like this:

```
inc/
---*.h
lib/
---CMSIS/
---STM32F0xx_StdPeriph_Driver/
---STM32_USB-Device-Driver/
------inc/
------scr/
---STM32_USB-Device-Library/
------Class/
------Core/
src/
---*.c
```

I've always thought these usb/ libraries were necessary to use the USB peripheral. Is this no longer true for the STM32F042 series? Or do I need to somehow figure out how to write my own versions of these files? I haven't been able to find any working examples of the STM32F042 using USB so I am somewhat at a loss.

Comment: I have no use for those libraries so dont know them that well.  The part does contain a usb interface as you well know.  it is not uncommon that they re-use the same peripheral across families.  not always a perfect borrowing from a prior family sometimes the clock/pll from A is mixed with timers and uarts from family B.  So first of course you should be asking ST not SO.  Second look at the datasheets for your two parts and see if the usb peripheral register specs are very similar, if not see if there is another stm32 device with library support and matching registers, and borrow that code.

Comment: if you are used to using these libraries the usb peripheral is the last one you want to go out on your own with and do your own driver.  There are no doubt open source or other libraries that support this instantiation of this peripheral. And highly unlikely that ST doesnt have library support for it.

Comment: SPL is dead for years and is not supported by STM. Use HAL instead. USB & Ethernet are quite difficult to program peripherals

Comment: @PeterJ_01 : The page for the [USB library](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcus-embedded-software/stm32-embedded-software/stm32-standard-peripheral-libraries-expansions/stsw-stm32092.html) he is looking for does promote STM32Cube as an alternative, but clearly states "ST continues its support for the software on this page...", so it is not true that it is not supported (although support may be limited to simply continuing to make it available -but that is all he is asking for).

Comment: I can't speak to the USB aspect, but STM32F3xx and STM32F0xx are significantly difference devices, so it is likely that the old Standard Peripheral Libraries are very different in this regard. The libraries will provide what you need. (of course, you can just use CMSIS at the register level, but USB is complicated.) That said, the newer HAL libraries included with STM32CubeMX are supposed to increase API commonality across the STM32 product lines, although they are still not identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the contrary; ST would like you to use their [*even higher level* library](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcus-embedded-software/stm32-embedded-software/stm32cube-embedded-software/stm32cubef0.html)!

However the library you seek but cannot find is clearly available for that part at the [STM32F042 product page](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/microcontrollers/stm32-32-bit-arm-cortex-mcus/stm32-mainstream-mcus/stm32f0-series/stm32f0x2/stm32f042c4.html).  Scroll down to the *Embedded Software* downloads section or search the page for "*STM32F0x2xx USB FS device library (UM1717)*" or use the direct link [STSW-STM32092](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcus-embedded-software/stm32-embedded-software/stm32-standard-peripheral-libraries-expansions/stsw-stm32092.html).  It includes examples.

ST would however really like you to migrate from their legacy software support to [STM32Cube](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcus-embedded-software/stm32-embedded-software/stm32cube-embedded-software/stm32cubef0.html).  Personally I dislike STM32Cube (even more than I dislike the SPL and USB libraries) for a number of reasons.  Unfortunately ST are reluctant to address bugs in the legacy support and in my experience most of their bugs are in the USB code, being much more complex than that for most other peripherals, but they are far easier to integrate into existing software designs than migrating everything to Cube and locking yourself into ST forever (which is of course their aim no doubt).